# How to know if a C++/CLI reflected parameter is long or int?

Tags: .net, reflection, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm reflecting a C++/CLI method that has the following signature:

```
void foo(long n);
```

This translates into C# as:

```
void foo(int modopt(IsLong) n);
```

How can I find if an *int* parameter is actually a C++/CLI long by reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `ParameterInfo` instance's optional custom modifiers:

```
bool IsLongParameter(System.Reflection.ParameterInfo p) {
   Type[] modifiers = p.GetOptionalCustomModifiers();
   return modifiers.Contains(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong));
}
```

Comment: It works, although, for some strange reason, it does not should the method signature happens to be void foo([Out] long n); :(

Comment: @AZ: Does the C++/CLI compiler attach a `IsLong` attribute to it in that case at all, or it simply decays to `int`?

Comment: Using Red Gate's .NET Reflector, it still has the modopt(IsLong) modifier. The complete signature in C# appears : void foo(out int modopt(IsLong) m);

Comment: @AZ: I've just tested it; it works correctly for `foo([Out] long n)` but the modifier doesn't show up for `foo([Out] long% n)` which is interesting considering that I have verified the existence of that modifier in IL with ILDASM: `([out] int32 modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong)& a) cil managed`. This is interesting. I'm not sure why that happens but it looks like a bug (or I'm ignorant about something).

Comment: I think the Reflection API is lacking that feature: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503412/custom-type-modifiers-modreq-modopt-are-generally-inaccessible-through-the-current-reflection-api

Comment: @AZ: I'd count that as a bug, not lack of a feature, since it certainly does retrieve the `modopt` from `long n`. It could easily retrieve it from `[Out] long% n` too.